# Delete/Destroy record on join_table with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, join

I render a set of checkboxes and I want to delete all the `Privilege` of a `User`.

- When I check one of the checkboxes, a record is created.
- When I uncheck one of the checkboxes, a record is deleted.

I have searched all the questions related, but unluckily none works.

Rails 5.2.3

**User**

```
has_many :user_privileges, class_name: 'UserPrivileges'
has_many :privileges, through: :user_privileges
```

**Privilege**

```
has_many :user_privileges, class_name: 'UserPrivileges'
has_many :users, through: :user_privileges
```

**UserPrivileges**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :privilege
```

The issue kick in when I want to delete ( uncheck ) the **last** privilege-record of that user in the **join_table**.

The record is still there, and there is no way to delete/destroy that specific record.

My intuition recall to the callbacks, I have tried different ways of using `dependent` but the last record is still there.

Any tips are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Using `dependant: :destroy` or adding a cascade trigger to the foreign key will both remove orphaned records. But you're asking about some kind of checkbox which means there are a lot more moving parts involved and the problem might not even be on the model layer.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: @demir not had the time to test it yet. Hopefully going to make it for today

Comment: Turns out it was an issue related to checkboxes and how we render them. So I think your answer was right, but not applied to my case. I leave here for future the link for `checkboxes` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`. https://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the record from the join table, you need to add `dependent: :destroy` to `has_many :through` relationship.

```
# privilege.rb
has_many :user_privileges, class_name: 'UserPrivileges'
has_many :users, through: :user_privileges, dependent: :destroy
```

See **What gets deleted?** in [API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> There is a potential pitfall here: has_and_belongs_to_many and
>   has_many :through associations have records in join tables, as well as
>   the associated records. So when we call one of these deletion methods,
>   what exactly should be deleted?
>
> The answer is that it is assumed that deletion on an association is
>   about removing the link between the owner and the associated
>   object(s), rather than necessarily the associated objects themselves.
>   So with has_and_belongs_to_many and has_many :through, the join
>   records will be deleted, but the associated records won't.

To run `dependent: :destroy` callback, you must use the `destroy` or `destroy_all` method when deleting the privilege record.

See **Delete or destroy?** in [API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> For has_many, destroy and destroy_all will always call the destroy
>   method of the record(s) being removed so that callbacks are run.
>   However delete and delete_all will either do the deletion according to
>   the strategy specified by the :dependent option, or if no :dependent
>   option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. The default
>   strategy is to do nothing (leave the foreign keys with the parent ids
>   set), except for has_many :through, where the default strategy is
>   delete_all (delete the join records, without running their callbacks).

Comment: Turns out it was an issue related to checkboxes and how we render them. So I think your answer was right, but not applied to my case. I leave here for future the link for `checkboxes` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`. 

https://www.sitepoint.com/save-multiple-checkbox-values-database-rails/